# Angularjs directives updating to changes in DOM attribute values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working on a scrollspy module for Angularjs. I've run into the problem where if the page is dealing with dynamic content, the scrollspy data (element positions) quickly becomes outdated. What is the angularjs way of dealing with issues such as this?

Should any directive that performs DOM manipulation `$broadcast` an event that the scrollspy module looks out for - allowing it to refactor its position data?

Should the scrollspy module check every x seconds for a change in scrollHeight with `$timeout`?

Or even better, is there a way to bind and watch for DOM attribute value changes (attributes such as `offsetTop`, `offsetHeight`, `scrollHeight`, not data attributes)?

Update: [Added code base to GitHub](https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/ng-ScrollSpy.js)

Comment: Constraining other directives to emit events would likely become unwieldy quickly and certainly make your module unfriendly to work with. There isn't an event for changes to the dim of elements unfortunately, so I am afraid a polling $timeout  impl is likely your best candidate. At least it is easily testable with $timeout.flush() :)

Comment: Being the devils advocate here, but what if element heights changed, but the overall `scrollHeight` did not... Suddenly you need to be checking everything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutation Observers seem to be the facility needed, unfortunately they are [only supported by the latest browsers](http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver).

```
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
if( MutationObserver ) {

    for ( var i = 0; i < spyService.spies.length; i++ ) {
        var spy = spyService.spies[i].scope.spy;
        var target = document.getElementById(spy);

        var config = {
            attributes: true,
            childList: true,
            characterData: true,
            subtree: true
        };
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                console.warn('mutation observation');
            });
        }).observe(target, config);
    }
}
else {
    console.warn('no mutation observers here');
    $interval(function() {
        angular.element( document ).ready( function() {
            console.log('refreshing');
        });
    }, 2000);

}
```

Currently searching for a polyfill that actually works.

EDIT: Added polling as a fallback if Mutation Observers aren't supported.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...  doesn't seem to update with CSS transitions though.

```
scope.$watch(function(){
    return elem[0].offsetLeft;
}, function(x){
    console.log('ITEM AT '+x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the code I'm stabbing in the dark a bit, but I would suggest your scrollspy module check every time `$rootScope` receives a `$digest` call. So use `$rootScope.$watch`.

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
  // Update scrollspy data here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, taken me some time to get back to this. Added link to the code on GitHub. Will this be called late enough though, once the DOM has been updated and rendered?

Comment: Yes it shouldn't get called until after AngularJS has finished loading directives and controllers and binding them.

Comment: Ran into $digest issues, probably just the current code structure however. Unfortunately this really only takes care of half the problem (assuming it works). A `div` that changed it's height on click for instance wouldn't be caught, unless it also called `scope.$apply();` which is basically the same requirement as calling a re-calc method...